# Error when building graph with bundle_graph/datashader

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews, datashader

I'm going through [this](https://anaconda.org/philippjfr/packet_capture_graph_hv/notebook) tutorial to learn a bit about datashader and bokeh.

Most of it seems to be fine, except a few examples. For example, this code:

```
    %%opts Nodes (size=5)
    graph = layout_nodes(hv.Graph(edges_df), layout=forceatlas2_layout)
    forceatlas = bundle_graph(graph, split=False)
    pad = dict(x=(-.5, 1.3), y=(-.5, 1.3))
    datashade(forceatlas, width=800, height=800, cmap=fire[128:]) * forceatlas.nodes.redim.range(**pad)
```

produces the following error:

```
      1 graph = layout_nodes(hv.Graph(edges_df), layout=forceatlas2_layout)
----> 2 forceatlas = bundle_graph(graph, split=False)
      3 pad = dict(x=(-.5, 1.3), y=(-.5, 1.3))
      4 datashade(forceatlas, width=800, height=800, cmap=fire[128:]) * forceatlas.nodes.redim.range(**pad)
...
    493         for i in range(10):
    494             for batch in edge_segments:
--> 495                 smooth(batch, p.tension, segment_class.idx, segment_class.idy)
    496 
    497         # Flatten things

TypeError: can't unbox heterogeneous list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're hitting [this bug](https://github.com/pyviz/datashader/issues/670), which is fixed on datashader master and will be included in the next release (Datashader 0.7). In the meantime, you can downgrade Numba to 0.38.1, which should avoid the problem.